# filezilla error Connection timed out in Ubuntu LTS 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, ftp

I want to connect ftp using FileZilla but its getting following error, instead when I connect to another host its connecting.

Anyone have any idea ?

```
    Status: Connecting to 205.186.187.210:21...
    Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
    Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
    Response:   220-You are user number 5 of 800 allowed.
    Response:   220-Local time is now 22:28. Server port: 21.
    Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
    Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
    Command:    USER picasolab@isisdemos.com
    Response:   331 User picasolab@isisdemos.com OK. Password required
    Command:    PASS **********
    Response:   230-User picasolab@isisdemos.com has group access to:  isisdemos.
    Response:   230 OK. Current directory is /
    Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
    Response:   200 OK, UTF-8 enabled
    Status: Connected
    Status: Retrieving directory listing...
    Command:    PWD
    Response:   257 "/" is your current location
    Command:    TYPE I
    Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
    Command:    PORT 192,168,0,101,25,213
    Response:   500 I won't open a connection to 10.76.202.170 (only to 111.119.248.61)
    Command:    PASV
    Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (205,186,187,210,214,69)
    Command:    MLSD
    Error:  Connection timed out
    Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```